# Update function with case SQL and VBA

Tags: sql, vba

I want to try to have a SQL function to update mine table and put a date in the column, I'm using a update function with a case, but I get the error that an operator is missing.

but I can't find the error, does anybody know where it is?

```
Public Function Add_date( _
                        ByVal startDate As String, _
                        ByVal strTableName As String, _
                        ByVal strFieldName As String, _
                        ByVal strNummeringField As String) _
                        As Boolean

Dim strSql As String
    strSql = "ALTER TABLE " & strTableName & " ADD " & strFieldName & " date"
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSql
    strSql = "UPDATE " & strTableName & " SET " & strFieldName & " = CASE WHEN " & strNummeringField & " < 25 THEN '23-07-1991' ELSE '01-01-01' END"
    MsgBox strSql
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSql


End Function
```

Comment: Can you print out strSQL before the two invocations?

Comment: Are you going to `add a column` to this table `each time` you execute the function?

Comment: Your backend isn't MSAccess is it? MsAccess doesn't support Case When.

Comment: this function is called once after creating a new planning, sow it only need to add the table datum once, the output og the las strSQL (because the firtst one works he creates the table): UPDATE tbl_voorlopige_planning SET datum = CASE WHEN Nummering < 25 THEN '23-07-1991'ELSE '01-01-01' END

Comment: mine backend is MSAcces but i didn't kown it does not support Case When sow there is mine fault, thanks alot

Comment: You can probably work around the lack of support for CASE...WHEN by using VBA's IIF() function. (Two *i*s, not a typo.)

Answer (score 1):

Jet/ACE (the MS Access db engine) does not support CASE...WHEN.  The equivalent for ternary operations is IIF (immediate if).  Also, date delimiters are `#`, not `'`.  Try this instead:

```
strSql = " UPDATE " & strTableName & _
         " SET " & strFieldName & " = " & _
         "     IIf(" & strNummeringField & " < 25, #23-07-1991#, #01-01-01#)"
```

Also, you may run into trouble formatting your dates as DD-MM-YYYY, regardless of your regional settings.  See [International Dates in Access](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the strings representing the table and column name contain invalid characters.  Try enclosing them in square brackets:

```
strSql = "ALTER TABLE [" & strTableName & "] ADD [" & strFieldName & "] date"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSql
strSql = "UPDATE [" & strTableName & "] SET [" & strFieldName & "] = CASE WHEN [" & strNummeringField & "] < 25 THEN '23-07-1991' ELSE '01-01-01' END"
```

Comment: i have tried your aswer, but VBA still gives me an syntax error operator missing